# cvs2git | git fast-import error fatal: Branch name doesn't conform to GIT standards: refs/tags/?

Tags: git, cvs2git

## cat ../blob.dat ../dump.dat | git fast-import

fatal: Branch name doesn't conform to GIT standards: refs/tags/?

fast-import: dumping crash report to .git/fast_import_crash_28075

After solving many issues got blocked due to above error while converting cvs repo into git by using cvs2git.

The error which is related to refs/tags/? but couldn't be find out the specific tag names which is causing problem.

does anyone have any clue or how to solve this error?

Comment: It's definitely this `?` tag. The data fed in to `git fast-import` has a known, well-documented format (see https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fast-import.html) so you could edit the input files, but it might be better to fix cvs2git to generate a valid tag name.

Comment: @torek,after followed the above article , got a different error  like "fatal mark:6885 not declared".                                   
 # git fast-import --export-marks=../git-tmp/git-marks1.dat<../dump.dat
fatal: mark :6885 not declared
fast-import: dumping crash report to fast_import_crash_27128               Note: i have done successful import of blob.dat but unfortunately got an error while doing import on dump.dat  .

Comment: Which "above article" are you talking about? (The only link here seems to be the one I made to the Git documentation, which is not an article.)

Comment: okay, its my typo mistake. do you have any idea about below error.      git fast-import --export-marks=../git-tmp/git-marks1.dat<../dump.dat fatal: mark :6885 not declared .

Comment: All I can tell you is the same information you can find in the documentation, which says that marks must be declared before they can be used.

Comment: even i've verified the tags and branch using  below command but it didn't  give any error.git check-ref-format "tags/<some-tag>" && echo "Valid tag" || echo "Invalid tag"

Comment: The problem you're reporting here is a *mark* not being declared; marks are internal to `git fast-import`, created by declaring them and then referred to by a later part of the input stream. If an earlier part of the input stream refers to a mark that has not been declared, you get that error.